# Is there way to turn off `ECHO` user input in `powershell`

Tags: windows, powershell, winapi

Linux has have `stty -echo` which make off typing so it is not echoed back to user.

So basically what you're typing is not seen on the shell.

Is there way to do the same in `powershell`?

Comment: What is the use case? Password input?

Comment: @ThomasWeller no, that's not a duplicate. `echo on` and `echo off` controls the echoing of texts from the batch file, not texts that user enter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, your intent was to **suppress echoing of commands provided *via stdin* to the PowerShell *CLI*** ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for *Windows PowerShell*, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for *PowerShell (Core) 7+*):

To do so, **use `-Command -` (`-c -`)**, which - *like* `-File -` (`-f -`, the default behavior) - accepts (independent) commands one by one via stdin, but - *unlike* `-File -` - neither prints a *prompt string* nor *echoes the command provided*:

- With `-Command -`:

```sh
# OK: Just the piped command's *output* prints.
PS> 'Get-Date' | powershell.exe -Command -

Friday, September 3, 2021 10:08:07 AM
```

- With `-File -`:

```sh
# Pseudo-interactive behavior:
# The piped command's output is: 
#  * *preceded by* the prompt string as well as the input command.
#  * *followed by* another rendering of the prompt string.
PS> 'Get-Date' | powershell.exe -File -

PS C:\Users\jdoe> Get-Date

Friday, September 3, 2021 10:09:44 AM

PS C:\Users\jdoe>
```

Note: In the examples above, a *single* command is provided via stdin (via the pipeline), and since no more stdin input is provided, the PowerShell process exits. However, in scenarios where you *keep stdin open*, you'll be able to feed commands - one by one - to the PowerShell process indefinitely.

**Caveat**: *Both* `-File -` and `-Command -` exhibit problematic, pseudo-interactive behavior; notably, a command spanning multiple lines must be terminated with *two* newlines; see [GitHub issue #3223](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3223) for details.

Note:

- Providing *neither* `-Command -` nor `-File -` is essentially the same as `-File -`, except that a copyright message is also printed on startup (which can be suppressed separately with `-NoLogo`); in short: `... | powershell -NoLogo` is the same as
  `... | powershell -File -`
- To provide a predictable execution environment and to avoid extra overhead, consider preceding `-File` / `-Command` with `-NoProfile`, which bypasses the loading of PowerShell's [profile files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles).
- **As for a *general* `stty -echo` equivalent** (the [POSIX-mandated `stty`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html) utility is available on Unix-like platforms, not on Windows):

  - This commands operates on the *terminal*, not the shell that happens to run in it.
  - A POSIX-compatible shell such as `bash` does *not* try to reset the terminal to its previous state after issuing this command, so input typed by the user indeed remains invisible through the end of the session or until the terminal is reset.
  - By contrast, PowerShell (the cross-platform v7+ edition that runs on Unix-like platforms) *does* reset the terminal after running each command, so running `stty -echo` is, in effect, a no-op.
  - In other words: **you cannot achieve the same effect in PowerShell**, on any platform (at least as of PowerShell 7.2)

---

On a loosely related note (prompted by a misreading of the question's intent), the following discusses:

#### How to hide or mask interactive user input solicited via the [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) cmdlet:

There is *no* built-in PowerShell feature (as of v7.2) that *hides* what the user types, but **if the intent is simply to *mask* user input**, so as to hide sensitive information being typed, such as a password, you have two options - both of which mask each character typed printing `*` instead:

Use [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) **`-AsSecureString`**:

```sh
$$valueEnteredSecure = Read-Host -AsSecureString -Prompt 'Enter your password'
```

Note that this outputs a [`System.Security.SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Security.SecureString) instance (which provides limited security on Windows, and virtually none on Unix-like platforms), which you can convert back to a regular string as follows:

```sh
$valueEntered = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new('', $valueEnteredSecure).Password
```

In *PowerShell (Core) 7.0+*, you can alternatively use (though note the simpler 7.1+ solution further below):

```sh
$valueEntered = ConvertFrom-SecureString $valueEnteredSecure -AsPlainText
```

---

**PowerShell (Core) 7.1+** now supports a **`-MaskInput`** parameter that exhibits the same UI behavior, but **directly returns a regular string**:

```sh
# PowerShell 7.1+
$valueEntered = Read-Host -MaskInput -Prompt 'Enter your password'
```

---

If **truly *suppressing* the display of all characters typed by the user** is a must, you'll have to create a custom solution that uses `$host.ui.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho')` in a loop:

Here's a simple implementation, which you can call as
`$valueEntered = Read-HostSilent -Prompt 'Enter your password'`, for instance:

```sh
function Read-HostSilent {
  param([string] $Prompt)
  if ($Prompt) { Write-Host -NoNewline "${Prompt}: " }
  $entered = $null; $done = $false
  do {
    $key = $host.ui.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho')
    switch ($key.VirtualKeyCode) {
      # Backspace
      8 { if ($entered.Length -gt 1) { $entered = $entered.Substring(0, $entered.Length-1) } }
      # Enter
      13 { $done = $true; break }
      default {
        if ($key.Character) { # printable?
          $entered += $key.Character
        }
      }
    }
  } while (-not $done)
  $entered # output
}
```