# Running multiple commands in the same instance of Powershell using C++

Tags: c++, powershell, cmd

I want to run multiple separate commands in the same instance of PowerShell using C++.

The first command would be cding into a folder containing a python venv.

`cd C:\\FolderPath`

The second command would be `./Scripts/activate` to run the virtual environment, with more commands possible later in the code.

I am aware of using ";" to separate commands in PowerShell, but for my purposes I would like to have separate command sets. For example something like:

```
auto cmdInstanceStore = GetCMDInstance(system("PowerShell"));
system("cd C:\\FolderPath", cmdInstanceStore); //Passing cmdInstanceStore runs the cd C:\\FolderPath command in the same cmd in which PowerShell command ran
system(".\Scripts\activate, cmdInstanceStore); //Passing cmdInstanceStore runs the .\Scripts\activate command in the same cmd in which PowerShell and cd command ran

//run more cpp code//
system("command 1", cmdInstanceStore); //Same idea as before, command 1 would run in the same cmd as  previous commands (command 1 would have access to env variable in the virtual environment activated earlier)
```

I am on Windows 10.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You need to  launch a `powershell.exe` process with `-c -`, then you can feed commands to it via stdin; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69036873/45375) may get you started.

Comment: @mklement0 that was useful, thanks.